# Parallel programming in R: functions not working

Tags: r, parallel-processing

This code I'm trying to run gets extremely slow as the datasets get bigger over time. I tried to use parallel programming to accelerate computation, but all my attempts fail. Often, it seems that I can't use package-specific functions (eg: `%>%`, `graph_from_data_frame`,...) in the parallel code. I tried using the `foreach` approach and reload the packages everytime, but to no avail. Can anyone help me set this up?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

set.seed(123)
year <- c(rep(2019, 4), rep(2020, 4))
from <- c(2,2,4,3,2,2,2,4)
to <- c(3,5,5,5,3,5,4,5) 
arithmetic <- c(runif(8))

# Create the data.frame
sb <- data.frame(year, from, to, arithmetic)
modu <- data.frame(year = c(1985:2020),
                   Modularity = runif(36),
                   EdgeType = "arithmetic")
cm_results <- data.frame(Year = integer(),
                         Measure = character(),
                         pvalue = numeric(),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# List of years and measures
years <- sort(unique(sb$year))
measures <- c("arithmetic")

# Loop through all years and measures
for (year_i in years) {
  for (measure_i in measures) {
    g_ari <- sb %>%
      filter(year == year_i) %>%
      dplyr::select(from, to, !!sym(measure_i)) %>%
      filter(!!sym(measure_i) != 0) %>%
      rename(weight = !!sym(measure_i))
    
    g_ari <- graph_from_data_frame(g_ari, directed = FALSE)
    
    k <- degree(g_ari)
    
    modu_random <- numeric(100)
    
    for (i in 1:100) {
      cm <- sample_degseq(k, method = "simple.no.multiple")
      cm <- as.undirected(cm)
      cm <- delete.edges(cm, E(cm)[get.edge.attribute(cm, "selfloop")])
      
      # Perform community detection using Louvain algorithm for random graph
      community <- cluster_louvain(cm)
      
      # Calculate the modularity value of the community partition
      modularity_value <- modularity(community)
      
      modu_random[i] <- modularity_value
      cat(i, modularity_value, "\n")
    }
    
    # Compute mean and standard deviation
    mean_cm_modu <- mean(modu_random)
    std_cm_modu <- sd(modu_random)
    
    # Calculate the Z-score and p-value to see if difference is significant
    modularity_values <- unique(modu[which(modu$Year == year_i & modu$EdgeType == measure_i), "Modularity"])
    if (length(modularity_values) == 0) {
      Z_score_al <- NA
    } else {
      Z_score_al <- (modularity_values - mean_cm_modu) / std_cm_modu
    }
    p_value_al <- ifelse(is.na(Z_score_al), NA, 2 * pnorm(abs(Z_score_al), lower.tail = FALSE))
    
    # Add the results to the cm_results data frame
    cm_results <- rbind(cm_results, data.frame(Year = year_i,
                                               Measure = measure_i,
                                               pvalue = p_value_al,
                                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
    cat(year_i, "\n")
    cat(measure_i, "\n")
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) the `modularity_value` are all zero; 2) don't `rbind` inside the loop, that's a big waste of time, create the data.frame with the final size then fill `pvalue` only in the loop.